# Scheduler does not call a class after push upgrade

Tags: scheduled-job, push-upgrade

I have a scheduler which runs every minute and it calls a @future annotation method. But whenever I update the org with the latest version of my package, the scheduler is running, but the particular class is not called and the functionality stops.
  So I have to abort and re-schedule the scheduler.

Can any one help me with this.

Comment: What does debug log says? What happens in postinstall class?  What do you mean by "particular class is not called"?

Comment: Is the scheduler also being updated when the latest version of your package is installed in the org? Is it a virtual class running as an instance or a regular schedulable running on it's own?

Comment: I am not installing the package, I am updating the package for an org.

Comment: And whenever I update, the scheduler is running, but the class which I have called in the scheduler is not called and there is no debug logs.